# Confusion Matrix of Bayesian Network

Tags: matrix, probability, data-mining, bayesian-networks

I'm trying to understand bayesian network. I have a data file which has 10 attributes, I want to acquire the confusion table of this data table ,I thought I need to calculate tp,fp, fn, tn of all fields. Is it true ? if it's then what i need to do for bayesian network.

Really need some guidance, I'm lost.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the question.  What task is your Bayesian network performing?  Is it classification?  If so what is being classified, is it one of the attributes in your data file?  More information would make this question easier to answer.

Answer (score 4):

The process usually goes like this:

- You have some labeled data instances
  which you want to use to train a
  classifier, so that it can predict
  the class of new unlabeled instances.
- Using your classifier
  of choice (neural networks, bayes
  net, SVM, etc...) we build a
  model with your training data
  as input.
- At this point, you usually would like
  to evaluate the performance of the
  model before deploying it. So using a
  previously unused subset of the data
  (test set), we compare the model
  classification for these instances
  against that of the actual class. A
  good way to summarize these results
  is by a confusion matrix which shows
  how each class of instances is
  predicted.

For binary classification tasks, the convention is to assign one class as positive, and the other as negative. Thus from the confusion matrix, the percentage of positive instances that are correctly classified as positive is know as the True Positive (TP) rate. The other definitions follows the same convention...

Answer (score 3):

[Confusion matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_matrix) is used to evaluate the performance of a classifier, **any classifier**.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is a confusion matrix with more than two classes. 
Here is the steps how you do:

- Build a classifier for each class, where the training set consists of
  the set of documents in the class (positive labels) and its
  complement (negative labels).
- Given the test document, apply each classifier separately.
- Assign the    document to the class with the maximum score, the
  maximum confidence    value, or the maximum probability

Here is the reference for the paper you can have more information:

```
Picca, Davide, Benoît Curdy, and François Bavaud.2006.Non-linear correspondence analysis in text retrieval: A kernel view. In Proc. JADT.
```